# how to find out which perl I am using when running a script with '/usr/bin/env perl'?

Tags: perl

With a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env perl` how can I make accessible to the script the perl I am using for running the script?
(Like in the `perl -E 'say $ENV{_}'` command line).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), there's the `$^X` variable you could use.

```
$ perl -e 'print $^X, "\n";'
/usr/bin/perl5.12.4
```

Comment: That works nicely when the shell is `bash`; when the shell is `ksh`, I got just `perl` printed when I typed `perl -e 'say $^X'` (this on MacOS X 10.7.2, where there is no `/proc` file system, much less `/proc/self/exe`).  This is not to say you're wrong; just to indicate that there are some platform dependencies lurking here.

Comment: Yes, doesn't work as well everywhere. The documentation in `perlvar` has a lot of info on the various ways it can fail/not work as well as you would want. I don't know of anything that would work better cross-platformly though.

Comment: @daxim: Why don't you post that as an answer? Should do better than a plain `$^X` on platforms/circumstances when that's incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eX).

Answer (score 2):

[`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5EX) is what one would normally look at

```
$ perl -E'say $^X;'
/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.14.2t/bin/perl
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't contain an absolute path on some systems. (I don't know why. Maybe it's because accurate information is not available on those systems?) [Probe::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Probe%3a%3aPerl)'s `find_perl_interpreter` works hard to find an absolute path if `$^X` doesn't contain an absolute path.

```
$ perl -MProbe::Perl -E'say Probe::Perl->find_perl_interpreter();'
/home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.14.2t/bin/perl
```